# How to validate all registered types in ASP.NET Core DI?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I want to check that the type registrations I established in `Startup.cs` are all valid at runtime (either when starting up the service or as part of a test suite). There's a [feature like this](https://jasperfx.github.io/lamar/documentation/ioc/diagnostics/validating-container-configuration/) in Lamar and other containers.

Comment: FWIW, you can use an alternate container if you prefer. Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection is just an easy to use and lightweight container. It's not the only option, and if you need more features than it provides, then you're free to use something else.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/tree/master/src/DependencyInjection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASP.NET Core 3.x actually introduced a feature for scope and provider validation. Both of these are useful in different contexts (see the below post and sample code).

```cs
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    })
    .UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
    {
        options.ValidateScopes = context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
        options.ValidateOnBuild = true;
    });
```

https://andrewlock.net/new-in-asp-net-core-3-service-provider-validation/

Comment: A nice writeup of limitations in that blog post. I'm bitten by no.4 _Factory functions aren't checked_. It seems to me that it should be feasible to implement without resorting to actually calling the factory function with a small change to its signature. If the factory function took a `Type[] dependencies`-parameter, declaring it's dependencies, it should be possible to reflect over that parameter and use the regular validation technique.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the services that you want to validate, and try to initialize a service with `GetRequiredService<T>`. It will throw an exception if there is something wrong. More info on 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.getrequiredservice?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: I'm not sure how practical that is given that some of the services might be scoped. You'll get an InvalidOperationException if you attempt to retrieve a scoped service outside the context of scope. Therefore, you'd either need some way to inspect the lifetime of the service beforehand or run the check both in an out of a scope.

Comment: One can create a scope, and do the checks inside the scope. Whatever satisfies the requirements of DI.

Comment: That's part of the problem... I don't want to rely on my memory in order to check all of the services that I registered. I told the container about them, it should be able to validate the dependency graph. It shouldn't need to instantiate (it's probably better not to fire off expensive factory funcs, in some cases). It just needs to check the graph, right?

Comment: Then I'm afraid @ChrisPratt is right. It will be difficult to expect the container to adjust required scopes etc. But if that's not a concern, you can encapsulate your service registration and save the service types in an array. You can just validate the service types in that array. I know it's not elegant, but it's a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

The [`IServiceCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iservicecollection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-3.1) is actually enumerable over [`ServiceDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicedescriptor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) which contains type information on the registered service and implementation. The service collection isn't usually registered, but it should be possible to capture both the service collection and service provider in a hosted service.

**Startup.cs**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddServicesValidation();
}
```

The right extension method can capture the services collection without actually registering it (which feels "safer").

```cs
    public static class ValidateServicesExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddServicesValidation(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHostedService<ValidateServices>(provider => new ValidateServices(services, provider));
            return services;
        }
    }
```

Now, the hosted service can iterate over the registered services & implementations. Although, this code bombs on the first generic `IOptions<TOption>`, but I'm sure we can figure something out?

**ValidateServices.cs**

```cs
    public class ValidateServices : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IServiceCollection services;
        private readonly IServiceProvider provider;

        public ValidateServices(
            IServiceCollection services,
            IServiceProvider provider
        )
        {
            this.services = services;
            this.provider = provider;
        }

        protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            using var scope = provider.CreateScope();

            foreach (var service in services)
            {
                _ = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(service.ServiceType);
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works great except with generics