# Is there any way to verify that we have registered all the necessary interfaces to the DI container?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

In .Net 6 we are using the default dependency injection mechanism by Microsoft. In most of our projects we use Scrutor to scan the assemblies and automatically register all the necessary services to the DI container.

The problem we have arrives to some of our projects where we don't use Scrutor or such. eg. in our Azure Function projects we register the services manually (eg. with `services.AddScoped`).

So, what is happening is that we register with `AddScoped` an interface and it's implementation and everything works fine. Then someone might go to the constructor of that implementation and might add some extra interfaces to get injected. So far, if the person doing that is using projects where we use Scrutor, most of the times running the projects will not have any issues, but... other projects where we manually register these services stop operating because they can't find the new dependency (as it hasn't been registered).

Has anyone faced something like that? This is a big trap as changing some class constructors might break other projects in our solution file and we don't have any way to know it unless we start running them one by one.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are seeking for a way to detect (or validate) missing dependencies? Newer versions of MS.DI actually have such feature built-in. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55126347/how-to-validate-all-registered-types-in-asp-net-core-di) answer, for instance. Whether that works in Azure... I don't know.

Comment: Hi @Steven. Yes. If the dependency is missing the app will throw an exception at runtime. The problem is that we have plenty of projects in the solution that might be using the same interface/implementation but not always they are registered. As such, we are forced to run them manually one by one to see if they throw exceptions... I am asking if there is any way to somehow avoid such issues during compile time or something.

Comment: Compile time? No. DI is something that is done completely at runtime. But you can ensure that this check is performed directly at startup, or as part of a unit test.

Comment: Thanks! I knew about that but I just hopped that something might had changed. Unfortunately it is quite difficult to run Azure functions locally just to see them failing in case any dependencies are forgotten to be registered. Having some 50 projects inside the same solution that use the same dependencies it is not difficult to forget to register a new dependency in the startup files of these projects (well... unless you use Scrutor that might be doing the registration automatically).