# .NET Razor pages, scoped dependency injection properties cleared on postback

Tags: asp.net, razor-pages

I'm trying to implement persistent storage on my Razor pages project. What I need is that on postback on my pages, the property values should not be cleared. I am doing this with dependency injection. I inject into the constructor of my page model the class which stores my property values, and I intend to repopulate the page variables after postback.

I intended to use AddScoped but it seems that on postback the class values are cleared. If I use AddSingleton then yes the class values are not cleared but I do not want them to remain populated when a user navigates to another page. I want the values populated while the user is on a specific page and does postbacks on that page, and cleared when refreshing the page or navigating to another. This way when doing a postback, I can repopulate the page variables with the class variables.

In Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDataService, DataService>();
```

My interface

```
public interface IDataService
{
    Models.User? User { get; set; }

    byte[]? LogoData { get; set; }

    public byte[]? SignatureData { get; set; }
}
```

My page

```
public Models.User? User { get; set; }

public byte[]? LogoData { get; set; }

public byte[]? SignatureData { get; set; }

public ProfileModel(ILogger<ProfileModel> loggerService, IDataService dataService)
{
    _loggerService = loggerService;
    _dataService = dataService;
}
```

When I submit a form on the page, the below method is hit but if I put a breakpoint at the start and check the contents of my _dataService class everything is null.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostRecreateApiKeyAsync()
{
    ...
}
```

My whole Program.cs file:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// If needed, Clear default providers
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();

// Use Serilog
builder.Host.UseSerilog((hostContext, services, configuration) => {
    configuration
        .WriteTo.File("serilog.txt")
        .WriteTo.Console();
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

// register my dbcontext from data project
builder.Services.ConfigureService(builder.Configuration);

// register services
builder.Services.AddTransient<IApiKeyService, ApiKeyService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IStripeService, StripeService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IInvoiceService, InvoiceService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDataService, DataService>();

// add support for Auth0
builder.Services
    .AddAuth0WebAppAuthentication(options => {
        options.Domain = builder.Configuration["Auth0:Domain"];
        options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Auth0:ClientId"];
        options.Scope = "openid profile email";
    });

// protect these pages
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/account/profile");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/account/usage");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/account/logout");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/account/billing/history");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/account/billing/paymentmethods");
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Comment: You should be adding not-null preconditions to your ctors - that will also help you detect when something fishy is going on... because what you're describing shouldn't ever happen, provided your pages are instantiated by Blazor's own factories which integrate with the DI container. Please show us your `Startup` / `ConfigureServices` code or equivalent.

Comment: I've edited the original post with my whole Program.cs. The Razor pages project does not have a Startup file.

Comment: I might suggest starting by adding DI validation to your `builder`, [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55126347/how-to-validate-all-registered-types-in-asp-net-core-di) - e.g. `builder.UseDefaultServiceProvider( o => { o.ValidateScopes = true; ValidateOnBuild = true; } )` - that way you'll get a preemptive exception on startup for misconfigured services.

Comment: Is there actually an issue with how I configured my services?

Comment: There might be - it's certainly a possible cause. Using `ValidateScopes` will help by either eliminating that as a possibility, or it will indicate that there's a problem. (I just wish MSFT enabled strict validation of these things by default...)

Comment: I added the line but got no exception on startup so the issue is elsewhere. Maybe this is expected behaviour if using AddScoped for a service in a page codebehind anyway?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in the `ProfileModel` ctor and looked at the call-stack to find out why the ctor args are `null`?

Comment: I admit the call stack is not something I've worked with before. I've just tried that and don't see anything of value. It just shows 1 line, the line that my breakpoint is on.

Comment: Ensure "Show external code" is checked, and "Just my code" is unchecked.

Comment: I've done that and pasted the results here. The breakpoint is set to the start of ProfileModel. Anything helpful here? https://pastebin.com/MHUz0hTD

Comment: When do you populate the class values?

Answer (score 0):

> When I submit a form on the page, the below method is hit but if I put
> a breakpoint at the start and check the contents of my _dataService
> class everything is null.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDataService, DataService>();
```

In asp.net core,scoped services keep the same instance for one request,when you submit a form ,you are making another request,you would get another instance of DataService instead of the instance you've set the properties in GET handler

```
 public void OnGet()
 {
     
     LogoData = ....//read from your other service?
     HttpContext.Session.Set("LogoData", LogoData);

 }

 public void OnPost()
 {
     if(HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue("LogoData",out var logodata))
     {
         LogoData = logodata;
     }
 }
```

You could try store the data into session,clear the session every time you send
a get request

add the reuired service:

```
builder.Services.AddSession();
```

middleware:

```
app.UseSession();
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    //when you refresh the page or navigate to another page,you are always sending get request

   // you could add a hidden input to record your current page,read it from HttpContext.Request.Form and check target page if you want clear session when you send post request to another page
    if (context.Request.Method == "GET")
    {
        context.Session.Clear();
    }
    await next.Invoke();
});
```